# Colab Notebook crash/restart cycle, followed by autosave failures and "Invalid Credentials" 2 days after upgrading to Colab Pro

Tags: google-colaboratory

I was just in the middle of working on an RL model and the notebook started crashing and restarting. It was never able to stay successfully connected to a remote instance. Then it began failing to autosave for a little over 6 minutes.

It may also be worth noting that before this began, I was trying to pip uninstall/reinstall to upgrade my version of numpy.

It eventually threw the following error in a modal:

> **Notebook loading error**
>
> There was an error loading this notebook. Ensure that the file is accessible and try again.
>
> Invalid Credentials
>
> DETAILS
>
> Invalid Credentials

```
Eb@https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/external_polymer_binary_extended.js?vrz=colab-20200218-085600-RC00_295745119:57:573
Ix@https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/external_polymer_binary_extended.js?vrz=colab-20200218-085600-RC00_295745119:867:76
SJ@https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/external_polymer_binary_extended.js?vrz=colab-20200218-085600-RC00_295745119:1538:170
pda/<@https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/external_polymer_binary_extended.js?vrz=colab-20200218-085600-RC00_295745119:1633:22
Ca@https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/external_polymer_binary_extended.js?vrz=colab-20200218-085600-RC00_295745119:17:336
Aa.prototype.throw_@https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/external_polymer_binary_extended.js?vrz=colab-20200218-085600-RC00_295745119:16:402
Ea/this.throw@https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/external_polymer_binary_extended.js?vrz=colab-20200218-085600-RC00_295745119:18:248
c@https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/external_polymer_binary_extended.js?vrz=colab-20200218-085600-RC00_295745119:26:299
```

Any and all help you may be able to provide is greatly appreciated!

Thank you

Comment: Does this error persist if you restart your browser? Or, try in an incognito window? Invalid credentials indicates an authentication error usually related to something like cookies, extensions, or logging out in a distinct tab.

Comment: I had tried restarting the browser, but the problem persisted. The incognito window appears to have solved the problem, though! Thank you so much!